# mounting IIS virtual folder in linux

Tags: linux, mount

Is it possible to mount a virtual folder exposed by ISS from linux? I have tried to mount it in Ubuntu and RHEL 4 over a LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A virtual folder in IIS is something completely different than a shared folder in Windows or any other OS. Virtual folders are just folders at web-browser level. Maybe if you allow browsing in this virtual folder, though I doubt this. But technically speaking, a virtual folder with browsing enabled generates a webpage where you could walk through the files and child folders, just like a regular folder. If there's something for Linux that can translate these kind of browse-enabled sites to a regular folder structure, then maybe. Otherwise, nope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve something  similar with reverse proxying technology.

E.g if you have a virtual folder on ISS example.com/myfolder you can make it available at http://example.org, so that end user will never know of your IIS existance.

[Nginx](http://sysoev.ru/en) is really good choice for such things.